# Difficulty with PIL - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Image

Tags: python, azure, file, python-imaging-library

I need to pass a cropped image to Azure Computer Vision API as a stream or a URL. Until now, for testing, I was cropping the image and storing it in a folder and reading that. Now I need to read the cropped image directly without actually storing it in my memory. This is my current code.

```
img = Image.open(path)
img2 = img.crop((bbox[-1][0], bbox[-1][1], bbox[-1][4], bbox[-1][5]))
            try:
                img2.save("C:/Repos/Dataset/Image_1/temp.jpg")
            except SystemError:
                #other code
            else:
                width, height = img2.size
                if (width >= 50 and height >= 50):
                    with open(img2, 'rb') as bg_image:
                        colour_analysis = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(bg_image, remote_image_features)
                        bg_color = format(colour_analysis.color.dominant_color_background)
                        bgcol.append(bg_color)
```

I need to change it to something like this:

```
img = Image.open(path)
img2 = img.crop((bbox[-1][0], bbox[-1][1], bbox[-1][4], bbox[-1][5]))
                try:
                    width, height = img2.size
                    if (width >= 50 and height >= 50):
                        with open(img2, 'rb') as bg_image:
                            colour_analysis = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(bg_image, remote_image_features)
                            bg_color = format(colour_analysis.color.dominant_color_background)
                            bgcol.append(bg_color)
                except: 
                    #some code
```

I get this error with the above code:
**with open(img2, 'rb') as bg_image:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Image**

How do I convert the Image object into a stream?

Comment: Why do you need to "open" the image if it's already in memory? Could you just set `bg_image = img2`?

Comment: Tried this, replaced bg_image with img2, and removed with open... get a whole lot of errors with the computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream function.

Comment: What you really need to be looking into/asking then is how to convert the `Image` object into a stream, or if there's a different function other than `analyze_image_in_stream` that you could use.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `open(...)` needs filename or access to file-like object - to read comressed data - but `img2` is filename nor file-like object but uncomressed image - data with pixel-by-pixel. You may use `io.BytesIO` to create file-like object in memory, save `pillow.image` to this file, and read from this file

Comment: you should also check if `computervision_client` has function to get data directly, not from stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.open()` gives you `pillow.Image` with uncompressed data - every pixel as separated item. But `open()` needs filename or access to file-like object with bytes data (compressed as `jpg`, `png`, etc.).

You may use `io.BytesIO` to create file-like object in memory, save `pillow.image` to this file (it will compress it as ie. `png` or `jpg`) and then use it to read it.

```
import io

buffer = io.BytesIO()     # create file in memory
img2.save(buffer, 'jpeg') # save in file in memory - it has to be `jpeg`, not `jpg`
buffer.seek(0)            # move to the beginning of file

bg_image = buffer         # use it without `open()`
```